# Ruby on Rails Association build and assign 2 related associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

So I've got a `User` model, a `Building` model, and a `MaintenanceRequest` model.

A user `has_many :maintenance_requests`, but `belongs_to :building`.

A maintenance requests `belongs_to :building`, and `belongs_to: user`

I'm trying to figure out how to send a new, then create a maintenance request.

What I'd like to do is:

```
@maintenance_request = current_user.building.maintenance_requests.build(permitted_mr_params)
=> #<MaintenanceRequest id: nil, user_id: 1, building_id: 1>
```

And have a new maintenance request with the user and building set to it's parent associations.

What I have to do:

```
@maintenance_request = current_user.maintenance_requests.build(permitted_mr_params)
@maintenance_request.building = current_user.building
```

It would be nice if I could get the maintenance request to set its building based of the user's building.

Obviously, I can work around this, but I'd really appreciate the syntactic sugar.

Comment: Activerecord scoping produces an abstract sub-class or collection. Subsequent methods apply to the latter collection. So,  basically, there is not much more you can do.

Comment: Thank you and you're absolutely right, this is what I am reading on atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Scopes) doc

> You can pass a second argument scope as a callable (i.e. proc or lambda) to retrieve a specific set of records or customize the generated query when you access the associated collection.

I.e

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :maintenance_requests, ->(user){building: user.building}, through: :users
end
```

Then your desired one line should "just work" `current_user.building.maintenance_requests.build(permitted_mr_params)`

Alternatively, if you are using [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) you can add hash conditions in your ability file

`can :create, MaintenanceRequest, user: @user.id, building: @user.building_id`

Comment: Omg! Thank you, but I don't quite understand how this works? It looks to me like I'm querying for specific building, but it assigns just as you said.

Comment: In fact, I can now write `current_user.maintenance_requests.build` and the building will still be assigned.

Comment: The scope modifies the association so that any maintenance requests accessed through a user have that scope applied. Rails knows how to apply the scope differently for find and for build/create.

Comment: Very nice! I've tried it out and it also works with any plain scope! Ex: `current_user.mainteance_request.pending.build` returns a pending maintenance request with user_id, building_id and status assigned. So awesome, thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I think the approach you propose is fine. It's one extra line of code, but doesn't really increase the complexity of  your controller.

Another option is to merge the `user_id` and `building_id`, in your request params:

```
permitted_mr_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id, building_id: current_user.building_id)
@maintenance_request = MaintenanceRequest.create(permitted_mr_params)
```

Or, if you're not concerned about mass-assignment, set `user_id` and `building_id` as a hidden field in your form. I don't see a tremendous benefit, however, as you'll have to whitelist the params.

Comment: I think you might be right, though it would of been sexy, it only really save one line.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to skip

```
maintenance_request belongs_to :building
```

since it already belongs to it through the user. Instead,  you can define a method

```
class MaintenanceRequest
    belongs_to :user

    def building
        user.building
    end

    #more class stuff
end
```

Also, in building class

```
class Building
     has_many :users
     has_many :maintenance_requests,  through: :users

    #more stuff
end
```

So you can completely omit explicit building association with maintenance_request

**UPDATE**
Since users can move across buildings, you can set automatic behavior with a callback. The job will be done like you do it, but in a more Railsey way

```
class MaintenanceRequest
     #stuff
     before_create {
         building=user.building
     }
end
```

So, when you create the `maintenance_request` for the user,  the building will be set accordingly

Comment: I totally agree, however... users can change buildings as these are residents and administrators. I do what you describe whenever I can, but I cannot find a way to persist the building, independently of the users "current_building".

Comment: I think this might be the most appropriate method as it sort of an unspoken business rule that a maintenance request building is the user's building at the time of creation! Very nice!